# clearInterval failing for incoming message alert, Seems to work, as messageBoxesCounter reverts to 0 but notification alert not sounding on next chat

Tags: javascript, alert, tampermonkey, clearinterval

I have a script that listens for incoming messages, Once the user starts typing or the message is sent, a notification sound is played so if you are not actively paying attention you will hear the notification and know they are typing to you.

I have the script working for the first chat. But when it detects the close chat button and is supposed to clear the `window.newIncomingMessageInterval` it looks like it works as the "Chat Alert: NOTIFY: ' + messageBoxes.length" is changed to 0 in the console output. But I won't hear the notification sound in the 2nd chat until it reaches the same message limit as the previous chat.

I am unsure why it isn't clearing the value correctly for the next chat.

I am trying to automate this script from a previous one that had a button you needed to click to start it.

But for the life of me I am unable to get this working the way I want it to.

This is a work project that I really need to figure out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
// SETTINGS

var notify = true; // true or false / to enable audio notifications on incoming messages.

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MAIN SCRIPT




var user_settings = {
    notify: notify
}

var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'https://PrivateDirectory/ChatAlert/notification.mp3');

(function($, user_settings) {
    'use strict';

    console.log(user_settings)
    var messageBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("div[class^='Body'][direction='Incoming']");
    var messageBoxesCounter = messageBoxes.length;

    console.log('Chat Alert: Cleaner Started');
    main();

    var cleanIntervals = function() {
        console.log('Chat Alert: Cleaning up Intervals');
        clearInterval(window.newIncomingMessageInterval);
        main()
    }


    function main() {
        window.newIncomingMessageInterval = setInterval(function() {
            var messageBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("div[class^='Body'][direction='Incoming']");
            var messageBoxesCounterNew = messageBoxes.length;
            console.log('Chat Alert: NOTIFY: ' + messageBoxes.length);
            if (messageBoxesCounter < messageBoxesCounterNew) {
                console.log('Chat Alert: NEW MESSAGE!');
                if (user_settings.notify) {
                    audioElement.play();
                }
                messageBoxesCounter = messageBoxesCounterNew;
            } else {
                console.log('Chat Alert: No new message');
            }
            if ($("button[data-testid='ccp-next-contact-button']").length === 0) {
                console.log('Chat Alert: Close contact button doesnt exist');
            } else {
                console.log('Chat Alert: Close contact button Exists')
                cleanIntervals();
            }
        }, 1000);

    }

})(window.jQuery, user_settings);
```

Tried to automate an existing script that had a button in place that you had to click at the start of each chat to enable the sound notification.

I have successfully edited the script for the first chat. But the notification sound for the second chat isn't working correctly.

Comment: Try defining the `messageBoxesCounterNew` variable after the `var messageBoxesCounter = ...` line.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by defining messageBoxesCounterNew, Any help is appreciated. or a push in the right direction.

Comment: your issue is with line `messageBoxesCounter < messageBoxesCounterNew` and line `if (user_settings.notify) {`